# macOS Sierra: Increase mouse cursor speed beyond System Preferences maximum

Tags: macos, mouse

I previously used [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) to override the maximum mouse cursor speed in System Preferences. However, as of macOS Sierra, this is no longer possible according to the developer ([source](https://github.com/fifafu/BetterTouchTool/issues/695)).

I am not sure if this is due to a technical limitation on part of the application, or if it indeed is impossible to override the maximum mouse cursor speed.

Note that I am referring explicitly to the *Mouse* cursor speed – not the Trackpad cursor.
 I am looking to increase the cursor speed of my Logitech Performance Mouse MX (without the use of Logitech Control Center!).

So the question is: How can the maximum mouse cursor speed be overridden (with a permanent setting) in macOS Sierra? Perhaps it could be done by a Terminal command or editing a plist file, but the solution could entail a third-party app.

Answer (score 15):

There are 2 FREE ways to accomplish getting mouse speeds over 5.0 accelleration on mac OS High Sierra:

1. First, is by executing the command-line:

`defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling  X`

where `X` is the amount of acceleration you want in the form of a number with one decimal space after it, then logging out, and logging back in. 
Therefore if you wanted to increase your speed to 8 acceleration you would type in the terminal the following command:

`defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling  8.0`

**Note**: If afterwords, you adjust the mouse controls in System Preferences again, you have to once again enter the terminal command and log out to regain your accelerated mouse settings.

2. Second, is to use an app called [mousezoom](http://benh57.com/mousezoom.html). It gets installed in preferences pane.

Comment: Thanks. Mousezoom worked for me. macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: @csonuryilmaz you are welcome! Glad you found something!

Comment: MouseZoom works in Catalina, too. But you have to `sudo xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine /Library/PreferencePanes/MouseZoom.prefPane/` to get it past the unidentified developer thing that Apple put there to frustrate users.

Comment: mousezoom works like a charm!
@frumbert thanks for the tip! It wouldn't work otherwise ;)

Comment: MouseZoom at max speed (10) works for me! @frumbert Thanks. Notice that the `~` is missing before `/Library`. The readme of MouseZoom was helpful for the step before that.

Comment: On MacOS Big Sur, the terminal command line didn't work for me, but MouseZoom did!

Comment: I had to restart my OS for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

My system runs 10.12.6. I used to use [usboverdrive.com](http://usboverdrive.com) for this, but found that (somehow) it interfered with Safari 11's cascading bookmark menus. Removing usboverdrive removed the menu issue.

Instead, I'm now using http://www.plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/. Steermouse also allows one to accelerate tracking speed. It doesn't interfere with Safari menus, and the website says it's "High Sierra ready."

Comment: Great app. Highly configurable. Regularly updated, now supports Big Sur.

Answer (score 3):

For those who have touble increasing speed beyond with multiple approaches ... try "inverted" option in this tool
http://triq.net/mac/mouse-acceleration
it speeded up my mouse to some number like 65000 factor ... and it finally feels like normal speed for mouse

Answer (score 1):

I tried using this utility (http://triq.net/mac/mouse-acceleration) with a Dell Mouse, and it seems to help increase the tracking speed of a mouse or trackpad beyond the default maximum value (up to 6 times). This tool also works with macOS Sierra. Try and see if it works with your Logitech mouse.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but 6x is not fast enough and seems to be roughly what System Preferences and/or BTT offers.

Answer (score 0):

This command works:

```
defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling  8.0
```

But:

1. System needs to restart before changes to take effect.
2. If you adjust the mouse speed again in system preferences, the increased mouse
   speed is reset to its normal range of speeds. So don't touch it.